# Sitecore 9 - Load testing results in 502 errors

Tags: azure, sitecore, load-testing

We have a Sitecore CD (Sitecore 9- update 1) Instances behind an Azure App Gateway.

I am doing a load test on our website with 4000 requests. I see that around 10-15% of our requests returning 502 gateway errors.

Our CPU and Memory Utilization (of Sitecore CD and Application gateway) seem to be fine. I have also examined CPU of SQL Server which looks fine as well. On examining the CD logs I don't see any errors or exceptions (I see few errors which are also seen before a load test as well). I just see 502 gateway errors at Azure app gateway and JMeter also says the same.

Any insights on what could be the reason for these 502 gateway errors for only 10-15% while remaining requests are successful?

Answer (score 2):

If auto scaling is enabled then while a new instance is standing up Sitecore is not 100% ready to serve requests yet when the new instance is already added to the load balancer. This causes the 502 proxy errors as the application gateway is not receiving the proper response from the new instance. This is down to the cold start and how your application initialisation is configured.

Make sure that you have the application initialisation in place to run a few requests to warm up a new instance before the load balancer will start sending requests to this newly created instance, *for example*, you can boost the cold start by specifying the Application Initialisation configuration in `web.config` for the critical pages as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
 <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
 <add initializationPage="/" />
 <add initializationPage="/key-section1/page1" />
 <add initializationPage="/key-section2/page2" />
 </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this issue by increasing the app gateway instances. We had 3 instances of app gateway and we were testing around 4K concurrent users. Roughly one app gateway instance can handle around 1K requests as per azure support.